# MS-SQL Database not added to AD-Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, amazon-rds

I have some trouble concerning the RDS / Managed AD connection:

I've set up the AWS Managed Microsoft AD and added some users.
Then, I've set up an MS-SQL Database in RDS.
Now, while accessing it via SQL Server Management Studio works flawlessly I simply cannot add the AD users I've created.
I get the following error: The program cannot open the required dialog box because it cannot determine whether the computer named "Network Name Resource" is joined to a domain

Looking at the AD, I can see that the RDS instance is indeed missing.
How can that be? In the RDS console I can it clearly being attached to the Domain?

Have searched this issue for quite some time and hope someone can help me out here...

Answer (score 1):

You must be signed into SSMS via domain account with privileges to add/modify users' logins for that search box to work.

Furthermore, it is non-obvious but you can confirm that your RDS instance is in the domain by using ADAC or ADUC and looking under: AWS Reserved > RDS